# Beta Binomial Distribution Derivation- Bayesian

Tags: distributions, bayesian, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

This is from Hoff's Book:First Course in Bayesian Statistics

How is p(y|θ) in equation (1) is similar or different than that of equation (2)?.
In equation (1) p(y|θ) is treated as joint probability of y given θ , while in equation (2)  ,p(y|θ) is treated as distribution.

[image]

Comment: In the first equation $p(Y \vert \theta)$ is the likelihood over several i.i.d. samples whereas in the second one $p(y \vert \theta)$ is the likelihood for a single sample.

Comment: Does that mean, (|) and (|) will be different?